# How to call confirm prompt using button_to in Rails with Turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

Previously in Rails when using the `button_to` tag, it was possible to use a confirmation dialog like this

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

`data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` is Rails magic data attribute that  was used by @rails/ujs library under the hood

Following Rails 7, this library is no longer on by default. Instead of this Rails use Turbo library

And now this code does not work

There is no information in official [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) and [Turbo handbook](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/introduction)

What I tried

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, data: { 'turbo-confirm': 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

But there is no result

I didn't find any solution on SO but found on Hotwire [forum](https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/button-to-not-showing-the-data-confirm/2046). This solution with Stimulus action. I just improve it a little

```
<%= form_with model: @post, method: :delete, data: { controller:  'confirmation', message: 'Are you sure?', action: 'submit->confirmation#confirm' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'Destroy' %>
<% end %>
```

```
// app/javascript/confirmation_controller.js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {
  confirm(event) {
    if (!(window.confirm(this.element.dataset.message))) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

It works but it's quite difficult and looks ugly, and we are used to Rails being cool

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Rails with Turbo without rails-ujs to call confirmation popup window with `button_to` we need to use code like this

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } } %>
```

or

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, form: { data: { 'turbo-confirm': 'Are you sure?' } } %>
```

Both generate `data-turbo-confirm` attribute

So we need to add this attribute not to submit button (like in rails-ujs) but [directly to form](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/4e828875b3c833ad4d978964a6a6f8a629c5d72a/app/assets/javascripts/turbo.js#L634-L647) containing this button (let me remind you this tag generates a form with button)

Comment: I have weird experience with `link_to` and `method: :delete`. It will do delete the current record, but weird enough to also delete its parent record.

Comment: @YakobUbaidi If your `destroy` action ends with a `redirect_to` (which I doubt is your case), some browsers will redirect to a new location with `DELETE` method, so make sure to add `status: :see_other` parameter to `redirect_to`, like the guides [suggest](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article)

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit complicated in 7.0.3, if it is a page that is using turbo it looks like this:

```
  <%= button_to "Delete",
                  user_path(user),
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button tight danger",
                  form: { 
                   data: { 
                     turbo_confirm: "Are you sure you want delete?"
                   }
                  } %>
```

This makes a little form. Now if you are using turbo, but not on that specific page, you no longer get the simple `comfirm: 'message'` from the old rails ujs. Instead you have to use stimulus controllers.

```
# app/javascript/controllers/confirmation_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { message: String };

  confirm(event) {
    if (!(window.confirm(this.messageValue))) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    };
  };
}
```

then

```
# app/javascript/controllers/index.js
import ConfirmationController from "./confirmation_controller"
application.register("confirmation", ConfirmationController)
```

then

```
    <%= button_to "Delete",
                  user_path(user),
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button danger",
                  form: {
                    data: {
                      turbo: false,
                      controller: "confirmation",
                      action: 'submit->confirmation#confirm',
                      confirmation_message_value: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                    }
                  } %>
```

It is a bummer that rails removed functionality, but if you want to use hotwire you need to commit to full buy in to the whole ecosystem.

Comment: This covers all the bases! With/without turbo!

Comment: doesn't work - Rails 7.0.4

Comment: works for me with Rails 7.0.4.2

Answer (score 1):

not the original question, but as of rails `7.0.4`, it would work the same (stimulus-free) :

```
<%= link_to("Del",
            del_path,
            data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Sure?" }) %>
```

Comment: doesn't work in Rails 7.0.4 - whole day looking for fix

Comment: you're running a fresh app ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding this, but the following worked for me

`<%= button_to post_path(post), method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } } do %>`

`an svg which shows a trash can`

`<% end %>`.

I also don't have anything that looks like the OP's `confirmation_controller`

Comment: It's the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994323/10608621 :)

Comment: @mechnicov Yes, but I'm confused; that link comes back to this page. But I didn't mean to take credit for the idea in any case.

Comment: this work for button in form, not for link_to

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when doing the Ruby on Rails guide [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

The answer above with using the `button_to` and `method: :delete` made the delete work, but the confirmation still wasn't working.

---

Somewhere along the way of me trying things, I stumbled upon mention of the `turbo-rails` gem. I found a working solution with these pieces:

1. Add this in the `application.html.erb` file:

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "turbo", type: "module" %>
   ```
2. Add `gem "turbo-rails", "~> 1.0"` to your Gemfile
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Run `bin/rails turbo:install`
   Note: not sure if this last step is necessary, but I was following instructions from [here](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails)

Using these steps, the code from the rails guide works, along with the confirmation dialog.