# confirmation message for deleting an article in ruby on rails, as it delete the article but its not showing confirmation message

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

the link is as follows:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete',article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call confirm prompt using button\_to in Rails with Turbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994322/how-to-call-confirm-prompt-using-button-to-in-rails-with-turbo)

Answer (score 2):

You tagged question as rails 7

Rails 7 use Turbo and new syntax is

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } }%>
```

Comment: still same result , no confirm message pop-up

Comment: @USAMAAZAM – did you find a fix for your problem?